# nested resources with optional verbs as resources in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to create my angular resource properly.

```
.factory('Favorite', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/user/:id/favorites/:verb/:favid', {
        id: "@_id",
        favid: "@favid"
    }, {
        jobs: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                verb: 'jobs'
            }
        },

        resumes: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                verb: 'resumes'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The trick is I want to provide a list function at `/api/user/:id/favorites` that lists all types of favorites (jobs, etc).

However each favorite type needs to have a CRUD interface for it.

So I also need to support GET/PUT/POST/DELETE for `/api/user/:id/favorites/jobs/:jobid`

I'm not really sure if I'm doing this right, nor do I know if I can actually do CRUD operations where the `jobs` and `resumes` are defined or how I would actually call them.